# dart to js: how do i get document of iframe

Tags: dart, iframe, dart2js, dart-js-interop

I am using Dart 2 JS to execute Dart code in the browser.

There is an iframe element (src is of the same domain) in my HTML.
I want to use Dart to get the `body` of the html inside the iframe.

```dart
final iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').cast<IFrameElement>();     // Works
final iframe = iframes.first;     // Works
final bodyInsideIFrame = iframe.contentWindow!.document!.body      // Compile time error
```

This does not work. The `contentWindow` is `WindowBase?`, and not `Window`. This means there is not `document` property.

When I try to cast `contentWindow` to `Window`, I get the following error at runtime:

```
Evaluation failed: TypeError: Instance of '_DOMWindowCrossFrame': type '_DOMWindowCrossFrame' is not a subtype of type 'Window'
```

---

Note: I can get the Iframe's body easily with JS. So since it's possible with JS, I don't see why it would not be possible with Dart that compiles to JS (Dart 2 JS)